# Documentation duplicates

Tags: bug, documentation

It seems at the moment documentation allows for duplicate topics. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3592/file-i-o#t=201607261552298174015

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3670/file-i-o#t=201607261552453179806

Comment: It's not a bug, _it's by design_.

Comment: @ken2k Then it should be a bug, I've just noticed another topic on the IO namespace just with a different name